# Jackson @JsonIgnoreType not working on static inner class

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have several model objects that are using the builder pattern which I am trying to serialize with Jackson through Spring MVC. Problem is, I don't want the inner static builder class to be serialized along with the outer class. I've tried using @JsonIgnore on the individual getter methods, but I just end up with an empty object. I've also tried using @JsonIgnoreType on the inner class itself, but that doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever. Anyone have any idea on how to get Jackson to ignore a static inner class? Thanks in advance.

Using Spring 3.2.2 and Jackson 2.2.1

**Simple class with builder**

```
public final class Address {
  private final String street;
  private final String city;
  private final String state;

  private Address(Address.Builder addressBuilder) {
    street = addressBuilder.street;
    city = addressBuilder.city;
    state = addressBuilder.state;
  }

  public static Address.Builder newBuilder() {
    return new Address.Builder();
  }

  @JsonIgnoreType // has no effect
  public static final class Builder {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    private Builder() {}

    public Builder street(String street) {
      this.street = street;
      return this;
    }

    ...

    // Java Beans setters/getters used by Spring

    public void setStreet(String street) {
      this.street = street;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
      return street;
    }

    ...

    public Address build() {
      return new Address(this);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

**Spring XML Config**

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="failOnEmptyBeans" value="false" />
    <property name="simpleDateFormat" value="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</bean>
...
<bean id="contentNegotiatingViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver" p:order="3">
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" p:objectMapper-ref="jacksonObjectMapper" p:extractValueFromSingleKeyModel="true" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Serialization Result**

```
{"builder":{"street":"1234 Some street"},"address":{"street":"1234 Some street","city":"Some City","state":"Some State"}}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{"street":"1234 Some street","city":"Some City","state":"Some State"}
```

**Here is the Spring controller that is used to return the Address object**

```
@Controller
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/address")
public class AddressController extends AbstractController {
  @Resource private AddressService addressService;

  @RequestMapping("/clean")
  public Address cleanAddress(@Validated({AddressGroup.Domestic.class}) Address.Builder address) {
    return addressService.cleanAddress(address.build());
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please show your code that passes object to jackson for serialization?

Comment: I have added the sample controller code

Comment: missing @ResponseBody?

Comment: Well it looks like that resolved the issue. I figured the <code>p:extractValueFromSingleKeyModel="true"</code> property in the view resolver would have the same effect. But I guess I was wrong. Thank you very much. Although, you would figure that the @JsonIgnoreType would take care of the problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `@ResponseBody` in your controller handler method.